# Spring DB connections can't be checkouted, but 290 of 300 connections are "IDLE"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql

I have a web application using Hibernate 4.1.1 and Spring 3.1.1 and Postgres 9.2. I also use spring transaction api and c3p0 connection pool. The DB server is located on another server and there is not installed pgbouncer, only Postgres.

I have many errors in log about DB connections can't be checkouted. But when I view status on Postgres server ("SELECT datname,procpid,current_query FROM pg_stat_activity"), 95% of these connections are "IDLE".

How is it happened? This ghost-connections can't allow executing normal queries.

Error:

```
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.TimeoutException: A client timed out while waiting to acquire a resource from com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@4bbf8a41 -- timeout at awaitAvailable()
```

Comment: It seems you are not returning those connections to the pool property, therefor they stay open but don't do anything. You need to debug your application to find out where you create the connection leak.

Comment: Could you explain me how find connection which not returned? Should I do some things beside marking service @tansactional and creating in DAO (@Resource bean) hibernate query? I am absolutely confused...

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue with Spring when i used Spring Transaction management.
C3p0 connection were lying idle and not getting reused, and when total connection upper limit was reached application gave db connection error.

Only solution which worked for me was to forcefully kill C3P0 connections [C3P0 provides htis option] after regular intervals. Its a bad solution and not recommended unless its the only solution which the my case.

Take a look at maxConnectionAge at htis url : http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#managing_pool_size

Comment: What the value you set to maxConnectionAge?

Comment: I set it to cleanup db connections after few hours as my application ran at interval of 2-3 hours, so selected a time after every 2 runs db pool was cleared.

Answer (score 1):

The connections are not returned to the pool. A common cause for this is using getSession().
Either rely on a thread-bound Session or use it in combination with releaseSession().

In general, it is recommended to use HibernateTemplate: getHibernateTemplate()